# ng.grid/ui.grid number of rows

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using [ui.grid](http://ui-grid.info/) so I got next question.

Rows in ui.grid datatable are wrapped by next div

```
<div class="ui-grid-row ng-scope"  ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" >
</div>
```

Now I got 25 records, but there are less than 25   in my HTML.
 $(".ui-grid-row").length  is always != 25.

Is there a way to display all rows as records I have.?
$(".ui-grid-row").length  === 25?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ui-grid provides row virtualisation - the explicit intent is that it only show a subset of the rows, allowing you to have 1000s of rows in your grid, but only force your browser to render a small number of them.

In general, if you want to render every single row, you might be better just using an html table than the grid - most of what the grid does is about virtualisation.

If you definitely want ui-grid for something, then you could look at the `virtualisationThreshold` setting: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions

In theory if set high enough this will render all your rows at all times.

Comment: I am in similar situation and using protractor to test the contents of the grid body. I also have 25 rows as result but shown are only 18 or 17 as rendered ones. Now I am expecting each row of all 25 rows to contain a text like `01-12-2015` . How to do this?`rows.each(function(row, index) {  row.getText().then(function(text) { expect(text).toContain(filterData.startDate);  }); });`